setfacl: default ACL & executable permissions
I have two issues with setfacl and exec permission
1/
I have a folder folder that I want to set the following default ACL:
setfacl -dm u::rwx,g::rwx,o:--- folder

This is the result of getfacl
# file: folder
# owner: user
# group: group
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---

When I go into the folder and creates a file. It does not get the executable permission.
total 0
-rw-rw----. 1 user group 0 May 22 18:57 file

I would expect this to be:
total 0
-rwxrwx---. 1 user group 0 May 22 18:57 file

Strangely enough, when I create a directory, it gets the executable permission
total 0
drwxrwx---+ 1 user group 0 May 22 19:01 directory
-rw-rw----. 1 user group 0 May 22 18:57 file

2/ The option X does not seem to work neither. I would like to use it so that directory gets the exec permission but not file.
When I use:
setfacl -dm u::rwX,g::rwX,o:--- folder

I don't see a capital X in the default ACL.
# file: folder
# owner: user
# group: group
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---

So it looks like x behaves like X should do as per (1) and X is just ignored as per (2).
is that a bug or am I doing sthg wrong?
setfacl v2.3.2 // btrfs
Thanks a lot

In short: work as design. In UNIX/Linux creation of the files do not set executable flag. It need to be added after the fact.
